# Will motherboard underclock fast memory to work with a slow CPU memory unit?

Tags: cpu, memory, motherboard, northbridge

Does a motherboard underclock memory in order to be used with a slower memory controller?

Specifically, if the CPU says it supports 1066 MHz Triple Channel and the motherboard supports 1333Mz memory, will 1333 MHz triple channel be underclocked to 1066MHz triple channel, or will the memory just not be supported?

I can provide more specific details if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the manual. There is no one answer fits all.

Usually and most likely the motherboard will under clock memory in order to be compatible. However, this is more to do with if the chipset supports the memory rather than the CPU.